# How can I create a table next to these lists? HTML

Tags: html, css

[image: this is the code]
How can I create a table next to these lists?

```html
<ol>
  <li>Administrative staff
    <ul>
      <li>Ali Alahmad</li>
      <li>Mohamad Batan</li>
      <li>Khandro</li>
      <li>Khadija M.</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>the teachers
    <ul>
      <li>B.Alham</li>
      <li>Musatafa</li>
      <li>M. Nour</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Services team
    <ul>
      <li>Alexander</li>
      <li>Alian</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Students
    <ul>
      <li> Omran Ali</li>
      <li> Aya Ali</li>
      <li>Samira Ali</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <ol>
```

Comment: There is no table in your HTML. Than you can use float, flexbox, whatever...

Comment: inline-block,inline-grid,inline-table,inline-flex, or just float on ol works. What have you tried, how wide is the table and the list in real  ,  is vertical alignement involved, etc. clarify ;)

Answer (score 3):

you can use css flexbox to achieve this. Here is the complete code.

```
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .flex-container {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;

        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="flex-container">
        <div style="width:50%;">
            <ol>
                <li>Administrative staff
                    <ul>
                        <li>Ali Alahmad</li>
                        <li>Mohamad Batan</li>
                        <li>Khandro</li>
                        <li>Khadija M.</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>the teachers
                    <ul>
                         <li>B.Alham</li>
                        <li>Musatafa</li>
                        <li>M. Nour</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Services team
                    <ul>
                        <li>Alexander</li>
                        <li>Alian</li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Students
                    <ul>
                        <li> Omran Ali</li>
                        <li> Aya Ali</li>
                        <li>Samira Ali</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <ol>
        </div>
        <div style="width:50%">
            place the code for table here
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here I have set the width of the div tags to 50% to make the columns equal width. you may change it if you need different widths for the columns.

If you hope to learn more on css flexbox, hope [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) link will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow Adam!

You can get a table next to the lists by putting both the list, and table into a `<div>` with the style `display: inline-flex`, like this:

```html
<!--This would be your list-->
<div style="display: inline-flex;">
  <ol>
    <li>Sample List
      <ul>
        <li>1</li>        
        <li>2</li> 
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  <ol>
</div>
<!--And this would be your table-->
<div style="display: inline-flex;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Test</th>
      <th>Table</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is a test table</th>
      <td>Sample Text</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</th>
      <td>More Lorem Ipsum</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!